# Python: possible to send text to a java app's stdin that is already running?

Tags: java, python, windows, stdin

I need to send text to a java app's stdin that is started independently from Python. I have been using pywin32 sendkeys up to this point, but there are some inconsistencies with the output that are making me look for other solutions.

I am aware of subprocess, but it looks like that can only be used to interact with a child process that was started by Python, not one that is started independently.

Socket is not an option for me because Windows does not allow multiple connections to the same port.

Comment: What environment are you running on? You could use a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have the java app read from a named pipe.  A named pipe allows multiple clients to write to it, and are language-agnostic.